# Upgrade to elasticsearch 5.5.0 and spring-data-elastic-version 3.0.2: ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.querydsl.QuerydslUtils

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to upgrade an application which uses spring boot and spring data elasticsearch.

> spring boot-> 1.5.8.RELEASE from 1.5.2.RELEASE
>   spring-data-elastic-version -> 3.0.2.RELEASE from 2.1.3.RELEASE

Here is my main application file code (related to elasticsearch):

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/repositories")
 public class TeyeApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate() throws UnknownHostException {
return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
}

@Bean
public Client client() throws UnknownHostException {
Settings settings =Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch").build();
Client client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings).addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));
return client;
}
```

When I run application it gives following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'whiteListRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/querydsl/QuerydslUtils
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
... 61 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/querydsl/QuerydslUtils
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.isQueryDslRepository(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:95)
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.getRepositoryBaseClass(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:79)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepositoryInformation(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:253)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:195)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263)
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.java:67)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
... 72 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.querydsl.QuerydslUtils
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 81 common frames omitted
```

I am trying to resolve this for almost 3 days but couldn't find a solution.

**Edit**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-elasticsearch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
```

Comment: Using a new major version of Spring Data with Spring Boot 1.5 is pretty unlikely to work. Also, you haven’t shared what you’ve done to try to make it work. What does your pom.xml or build.gradle look like?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson added pom dependencies, please see the updated question.

Comment: I am facing exactly the same issue, but i don't use spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch. my gradle-config is just:
 compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:3.0.2.RELEASE')
 compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.5.9.RELEASE')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.5.9.RELEASE')